# How to query 3 tables in PSQL?

Tags: postgresql, select, data-warehouse, querying

I am new to databases, I am not sure how to query these 3 tables.

I am trying to find out the total deaths(Table COVID - TotalDeathUK) of each strain(Table Strain) for the last 1 year(Table - Time?)

Table COVID

```
 centerid | patientid | dateid | strainid | totaldeathsuk | 
----------+-----------+--------+----------+---------------+
   100000 |    100000 | 100000 |   100000 |         31369 |       
   100000 |    100000 | 100000 |   100000 |         95382 |       
   100004 |    100004 | 100004 |   100000 |         46031 |

----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table Strain

```
 strainid |   name    | risk 
----------+-----------+------
   100000 | Fixflex   |   50
   100001 | Cardguard |   85
   100002 | Zaam-Dox  |   53
```

Table Time

```
 dateid | year |    month     | quater | week | dayofweek |   hour   
--------+------+--------------+--------+------+-----------+----------
 100007 | 2039 | Thin Ice     |      2 |    3 |         7 | 11:54:00
 100008 | 2109 | Parineeta    |      4 |    1 |         6 | 20:12:00
 100011 | 2096 | Crawlspace   |      4 |    2 |         7 | 19:03:00
```

Link to Image of the Database Schema

[image]

Comment: What do you think you meant to select when you selected [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info)?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Are you asking if that is a good design? If so, no.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I am asking how to query these 3 tables

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want to find out for example if  theTotalDeathsUk is 31369, the Strain name for the last 1 year

Comment: But what is patientId, dateId ..., totaldeathUK is then? It is confusing to see totalSomething per patientId, dateId, ... Would you please show the expected output for your data.

Comment: @CetinBasoz basically this is supposed to be a Data Warehouse, the table covid is a fact table, I followed some google designs which I found, I asked my lecturer for feedback he told me there is no such a thing as wrong and right. This is supposed to support decision making

Comment: @GIvanov\ I am sure your lecturer didn't mean this design when he said that. Anyway, I asked for an explanation of your data and expected output. making the joins and query is the easy part but at this stage we need to understand what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Covid(CenterID int,PatientID int, DateID int,StrainID int,TotalDeathUK int);
> CREATE TABLE Strain(StrainID int, Name varchar(20),Risk int);
> CREATE TABLE Time(DateID int,Year int,Month varchar(20),Quarter int,Week int,DayOfWeek int,Hour varchar(8))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Covid(CenterID,PatientID, DateID,StrainID,TotalDeathUK)
> VALUES(100000,100000,100000,100000,31369),
> (100000,100000,100008,100000,95382),
> (100004,100004,100011,100000,46031);
> INSERT INTO Strain(StrainID, Name,Risk)
> VALUES( 100000,'Fixflex ',50),( 100001,'Cardguard ',85)
> ,( 100002,'Zaam-Dox ',53);
> INSERT INTO Time(DateID,Year,Month,Week,Quarter,DayOfWeek,Hour)VALUES(100000,2020,'Thin Ice',2,3,7,'11:54:00'),
> (100008,2019,'Parineeta',4,1,6,'20:12:00'),
> (100011,2018,'Crawlspace',4,2,7,'19:03:00');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT T.Year,S.StrainID,C.TotalDeathUK FROM Covid AS C
> LEFT JOIN Strain AS S ON S.StrainID=C.StrainID
> LEFT JOIN Time AS T ON T.DateID=C.DateID
> WHERE T.Year=date_part('year', (SELECT current_timestamp))-1
> ```

> ```
> year | strainid | totaldeathuk
> ---: | -------: | -----------:
> 2020 |   100000 |        31369
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2e108686adbd1d64fa763c750a60868b)*